# As I Was Reflecting On Nothing

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

> I have a teenage cousin. He’s a real 2. I can’t believe this 11. It’s not even 14 and already he’s in deep 16. The worst part is, he doesn’t give a 20. I mean, I showed him this and guess what his reaction was? 12!

What words? What pattern?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reflecting on Nothing =

> Palindromes centered on at least one letter O (which resembles 0 or nothing)

Also,

> As others have suggested, numbers stand for the corresponding letter in lexicographic order.

Thus,

> I have a teenage cousin. He’s a real **BOOB**. I can’t believe this **KOOK**. It’s not even **NOON** and already he’s in deep **POOP**. The worst part is, he doesn’t give a **TOOT**. I mean, I showed him this and guess what his reaction was? **LOL**!

Comment: This seems like it could (should) be the answer. If not, it gets the *best wrong answer* trophy.

Comment: A teenager of my acquaintance (not actually my cousin) tells me that he and his friends laugh outrageously out loud. I don’t know what’s wrong with kids these days. *My* generation was perfectly content to roll on the floor laughing. Congrats!

Comment: 23 - excellent puzzle and solution.  Good one for 13 or 16 to ask even a 20? 12 :P

Answer (score 8):

I think the words are

> Related to the alphanumerics translation of the numbers.

My stab at this:

> I have a teenage cousin. He’s a real 2 **B$%^#.....OZO** *(A real bozo, yes that's the word)*. I can’t believe this 11 **KID**. It’s not even 14 **NOON** and already he’s in deep 16 **PROBLEMS**. The worst part is, he doesn’t give a 20 **TOSS**. I mean, I showed him this and guess what his reaction was? 12 **LOSER**!

Comment: A good start, but the title is key!

Answer (score 7):

I hope these initial thoughts are not too elementary but it seems

> the symbols of the chemical elements of these numbers start suitable words.

He’s a real 2.

> He’s a real 2 - atomic number 2 is helium so he's a real **He**adache - thanks to El-Guest!!!

I can’t believe this 11.

> I can’t believe this 11 - sodium and [Na](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/a) is not applicable or no answer so don't believe it.

It’s not even 14 and already he’s in deep 16.

> It’s not even 14 - silicon Si starts **Si**x - and already he’s in deep 16 - sulphur S for **S**h!t.

The worst part is, he doesn’t give a 20.

> The worst part is, he doesn’t give a 20 - calicum Ca for **Ca**re.

I mean, I showed him this and guess what his reaction was? 12!

> ...  his reaction was? 12! - magnesium Mg is initials of **M**y **G**od

Title: As I Was Reflecting On Nothing

> **As** = arsenic, **I** = iodine, **W** = tungsten,**Re** = rhenium, **O** = oxygen, **N** = nitrogen.

Comment: For 2, it could also be r13(urnqnpur)?

Comment: @El-Guest, thank you that goes better than what I had. Also really like your answer!

Comment: Thank you very much, Tom! Much appreciated :) I'm still thinking about 11, because I think there might be something more for it, but I think your answer is great!! (+1) from me for sure!

Comment: For 11, all I can come up with is r13(abfl n%fu&#r), but I _strongly doubt_ that is the correct answer ;P

Comment: @El-Guest - lol :) that does describe some people, but surely OP wouldn't clue that!

Comment: I’m afraid all my words are rated gallium (General admission)

Answer (score 2):

I had two thoughts on this based on the title so:

### Guess 1

> So I looked at the title and thought of "On Nothing" must mean zero. So an alphnumeric solution should use zero as its index. Giving us: C, L, O, Q, U, & M.

Using that method I came up with this:

> I have a teenage cousin. He's a real *Character* (or *Card*). I can't believe this *Loser*. It's not even *One* and already he's in deep *Quagmire*. The worst part is, he doesn't give a *Uff* (like "whew!" or just "uff! really?!"). I mean, I showed him this and guess what his reaction was? *Mook*!

But there is another word in the title which made me think I needed to do more:

### Guess 2

> "Reflecting (flip order of letters) on nothing (zero index)" -> so reverse the order and we get M, U, O, L, & C. Maybe that's it, maybe it is talking about a mirror or the reflection in the mirror.

Applying this new solution gave me:

> I have a teenage cousin. He's a real *Mirror*. I can't believe this *Useless furniture* and he's in deep *Oak (color or wood)*. The worst part is, he doesn't give a *Look*. I mean, I showed him this and guess what his reaction was? *Crash* (it broke)